# How can you import portfolio projects in react?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I'm making a portfolio with react. How can I navigate to my projects through my localhost:3000? They are in my includes folder and the projects aren't made with react. It seems not to be the same as using XAMPP as my sever.

My file structure is:

`-src
   -componets
      -sectionB.js
   -imports
     -myproject1
       -index.php`

I'm trying to go to my project with an `<a>` tag with this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'

class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

        <a className="proj-card" href={this.props.href}>
          <h2>{this.props.projName}</h2>
          <img src={this.props.img}/>
          <span>Technolgies: ({this.props.tech})</span>
          <p>{this.props.projdesc}</p>
        </a>
    )
  }
}

class SectionB extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sectionB">

        <Card projdesc={...} img={...} tech="..." projName="..." href="./imports/calendar2/index.php"/>

      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default SectionB;
```

Why is this not directing the url to my project?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're supposed to be using [Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md) from react-router-dom. That may be a place to start. And what happens when you change:

```
<Card projdesc={...} img={...} tech="..." projName="..." href="./imports/calendar2/index.php"/>
```

to

```
<Card projdesc={...} img={...} tech="..." projName="..." href="../imports/calendar2/index.php"/>
```

Comment: Also, remember your to-values need to be going to an absolute or relative path from the browser's point of view, not the component's. So, for example, if src/imports/myproject/ is the root, then you need to make the to-value just /index.php

Comment: ../ is the same, that is what I'm confused about I don't know why a relative path wont work.